# close and reset height and width to its original sizes on "close" click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="box">
     <div class="info">
          <p>..some content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <div class="info">
          <p>..some content..</p>
          <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Since I don't know .box height as it will expand and its height will depend on .info content, i run this:

```
 $('.box').each(function() {
     $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
 });
```

When I click "close" once .box has expanded, I should be able to close expanded .box and reset its height and width to its original sizes before it was expanded.

I tried to run this, which is inside another function and it doesn't get the correct height:

```
$(".close").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".info").empty();
    $(".box").width(251);
    $(".box").data('height');
});
```

Anyone?

Comment: Any particular reason why this can't be done using standard layout CSS techniques?  You could just remove or hide .info and let the 'box' flow back to its normal state.

Comment: because in reality the content into .info is loaded via ajax and i am setting the new height and width with jquery. have to do that for a whole bunch of reasons in regards of vimeo.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  Now that you've posted a close method, take a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your .close method:

```
$(".close").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".info").empty();
    $(".box").width(251);
    $(".box").data('height'); // Just retrieves the height value
});
```

I think you're trying to do this?

```
$(".close").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".info").empty();
    $(".box").width(251);
    // Sets the element's height to the stored height value
    $(".box").height( $(".box").data('height') );
});
```

Comment: No problem!  If this solved the issue for you, consider marking this as the selected answer.